# How to resolve error 'Access to fetch at from origin has been blocked by CORS policy' in Blazor App

Tags: c#, cors, blazor

I've been searching a lot in the Internet about CORS but I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong.

The errors i'm getting in the console of my browser is:

*Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:44361/api/Contracts' from origin 'https://localhost:44337' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.*

*GET https://localhost:44361/api/Contracts net::ERR_FAILED*

The **method** in my Blazor WebAssembly App for **getting data**:

```
public class ContractsUIRepository : IContractsUIRepository
{
    private readonly IHttpService _httpService;
    private readonly string url = "api/Contracts";
    public ContractsUIRepository(IHttpService httpService)
    {
        _httpService = httpService;
    }
    
    public async Task<List<ContractDTO>> GetAllContracts()
    {
        var response = await _httpService.Get<List<ContractDTO>>(url);
        if (!response.IsSucceed)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(await response.GetBodyOfResponse());
        }
        return response.Response;
    }
}
```

My **HttpService.cs**:

```
public class HttpService : IHttpService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    public HttpService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseWrapper<T>> Get<T>(string url)
    {
        var httpResponseMessage = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);
        if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var response = await Deserialize<T>(httpResponseMessage);
            return new HttpResponseWrapper<T>(true, response, httpResponseMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            return new HttpResponseWrapper<T>(false, default, httpResponseMessage);
        }
    }

    private static async Task<T> Deserialize<T>(HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage)
    {
        var responseString = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseString);
    }
}
```

The **HttpResponseWrapper.cs**:

```
public class HttpResponseWrapper<T>
{
    public bool IsSucceed { get; set; }
    public T Response { get; set; }
    public HttpResponseMessage HttpResponseMessage { get; set; }

    public HttpResponseWrapper(bool isSucceed, T response, HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage)
    {
        IsSucceed = isSucceed;
        Response = response;
        HttpResponseMessage = httpResponseMessage;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetBodyOfResponse()
    {
        return await HttpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

My **Program.cs** in the **Client** Project:

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44361/") });

        builder.Services.AddScoped<IHttpService, HttpService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IContractsUIRepository, ContractsUIRepository>();

        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
}
```

And finally my **Startup.cs** file in the **Server** Project:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "HAFProcurement.WebAPIs", Version = "v1" });
        });

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("default", policy =>
            {
                policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44337/")
                      .AllowAnyHeader()
                      .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        });
        
        services.AddSingleton<IDataAccess, OracleDataAccess>();
        services.AddSingleton<IContrRepository, ContrInMemory>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Procurement.WebAPIs v1"));
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors("default");
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

I am new to C# & Blazor and I am stuck right now. I need your help!

Additionally, is something wrong with my **HttpService.cs** file? Because I'm not sure it's right..

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you try moving app.UseCors("default") to beginning of Configure method so that it will be called first in pipeline and run the service again.

Comment: I had already tried it. Didn't work. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the backslash from the url at builder.WithOrigins:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("default",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44337")
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});
```

Use `https://localhost:44337` instead of `https://localhost:44337/`

Comment: You' re right! I totally overlooked it. Thank you very much!